# C++, g++, conditional compilation based on host name?

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have come across the following problem:

Our testing environment is not able to fully simulate a certain hardware part of the production environment, and therefore some code needs excluding when testing the application.

I therefore need something in the way of

```
 #IFNDEF testing_env
 //code to exclude
 #ENDIF
```

This works just fine if i include a `#DEFINE testing_env`, but like this i need to manually comment/uncomment this define every time i switch environments.

I'm looking for a way to do this based on the host name or a similar feature. I have tried to look for conditional compilation based on environment variables, but apparently this is not possible.

Comment: apparently it is possible to use environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184148/can-i-define-an-environment-variable-and-use-it-in-conditional-compilation

Comment: Why not just move it to `test runner level`? Run on not run test depedn on any environment properties.

Comment: Wouldn't `-D testing_env` work?

Comment: I guess, the easiest way would be to make this in the build script i.e. make defines (`-D`) depending on environment variables or something similar.

Comment: The link you posted is Visual Studio specific, I'm using QtCreator and g++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you create a specific build profile for the testing env (dedicated make rules) and another build profile (other make rules) for the other environments.

Test environment can then be specified with -DTEST_ENVIRONMENT on the compilation line (usually in the Makefile), eg. of use of -D option:

`g++ -DTEST_ENVIRONMENT -o test main.c`

then

```
#IFNDEF TEST_ENVIRONMENT
//code to exclude
#ENDIF
```

will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Makefile can determine the hostname and set the specific vars with `-D` for your build:

Example:

```
HOSTNAME=$(shell hostname)

ifeq ($(HOSTNAME), localhost1.localdomain)
    ANY_VAR=COMPILE_VERSION_1
else
    ANY_VAR=COMPILE_VERSION_2
endif

$(info $(HOSTNAME))
$(info $(ANY_VAR))

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -D$(ANY_VAR) $< -c

OBJECTS=main.o

go: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $^ -o go

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f go
```

Your C/C++ can use this vars with something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef COMPILE_VERSION_1
std::string x="Version1";
#endif

#ifdef COMPILE_VERSION_2
std::string x="Version2";
#endif

int main()
{   
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```