# Visual Studio: user depended defines

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In our team is an old developer, who likes Debug-Message-Boxes. Not for just the current debugging session, no, forever. So when running the program in debugging mode, the boxes are nagging all the other developers. But we are not allowed to remove the boxes.

So, is there a possibility to define a DEFINE deepened on user / computer? So, we can do this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #ifndef NONAG
        MessageBox(...);
    #endif
#endif
```

-> and now, we can define "NONAG" and have more fun..

Thanks

Comment: I'm talking about a setting the other developer can set in VS.

Comment: This can give you an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184148/can-i-define-an-environment-variable-and-use-it-in-conditional-compilation/25184777#25184777

Comment: custom MessageBox that checks user. Or a prebuilt step that generates a file with custom defines (based on user)

Comment: Upvoted just because the situation is at the same time so funny, so ridiculous,  and so realistic.. I know what you feel @RalphErdt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a standard setup, a `{ProjectName}.vcxproj.user` props file will be created next to your normal project.

Its a standard props file which shouldn't be checked into source control and so lets each individual user set personal project settings including preprocessor macros. So change that file to be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NONAG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Alternatively you can setup custom props file by including something like in your project or common props file:

```
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  <Import Project="{some custom props file path}" Condition="exists('{some custom props file path}')"/>
</ImportGroup>
```

Comment: This is Visual Studio specific. +1 if the reply has information on alternatives (other build systems, generated files, runtime config files) :)

Comment: The question is about visual studio - its in the tags.